# Track changes in List<XElement>

Tags: c#, xml, performance

I have 4 dictionaries (Added, Removed, Updated), every 1 minute I am downloading an XML file and I put a unique ID to the KEY of the dictionary and the XML itself in the VALUE.

XML Looks like:

```
<Worker ID="1" Name="James Smith">
    <Details Key="" Value="" />
    <Details Key="" Value="" />
    <Details Key="" Value="" />
    <Details Key="" Value="" />
    <Details Key="" Value="" />
</Worker>
```

So in this case I put the Worker's ID in the KEY and the entire XML in the value.

The logic should be:

```
* if ID doesn't exist, it should be inserted to Added.
* if ID exists and was changed it should be added to Updated.
* if ID was removed, it should be added to Removed.
```

With every run, the dictionaries should reset themselves, so I get only the last run changes.

I was wondering what is the most efficient way to track the XML changes in the fastest way?

Answer (score 0):

They're Dictionary collections, right? They can only hold one value for each distinct key.

So you do this:

```
 if (dict.ContainsKey(workerId)) {
     dict[workerId] = newXmlValue;
 }
 else {
     dict.Add(workerId,newXmlValue);
 }
```

I don't completely understand the "removed" part of your question.  But it's easy to remove a value from a dictionary.

```
dict.Remove(workerId);
```

If the particular workerId key isn't already in the dictionary, this will put it there. If it is, it will update the newXmlValue to the latest and greatest.

This is about as efficient a data structure as you can get with dot net, both in time and memory usage.